# How to add a row to a JTable using AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, user-interface, jtable, listener, abstracttablemodel

I want the user to click a button called "Add new" and when that happens the data in the text fields is entered into the table. I want to have an inner listener class looking after that, but I am unsure how to go about it.

Comment: Well, you add a method to your model class that adds a row to its inner data structure (a list, presumably) holding the rows. And which fires the appropriate event signalling that a row has been added. At least try something, and post your code.

Comment: What have you try?, what are the options are you planning? what makes you unsure? how you wanna write the class? This is a really broad question

Answer (score 0):

I attach you a full solution in which I have coded:

1. Example class (extends JFrame)
2. TableModelCustom class (extends AbstractTableModel)

You can use and see how change the data table when you click on the two buttons.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

/**
 * Example class to learn how to use AbstractTableModel
 * 
 * @author Moreno
 *
 */
public class Example extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; // default serialVersionUID

    /**
     * Example class, is a JFrame
     * 
     */
    public Example() {
        super("Example");

        TableModelCustom myModel = new TableModelCustom();  //Create my table model
        JTable table = new JTable(myModel);                 //Create JTable
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(480, 70));   //Prefered size scroll

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);    //Create scroll with table

        JButton button = new JButton("Click me");           //Create JButton
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Click me2");         //Create JButton2
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {     //Listener onClick...

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Change data
                Object[][] data = { { "Rick", "Mourt", "Main Street", 55, true} };

                //Send data to the model
                myModel.setData(data);
            }
        });

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {        //Listener onClick...

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Change data
                Object[][] data = { { "Thomas", "Mourt", "Main Street 50", 55, true },
                        { "Rich", "Fua", "Main Street 2", 25, false }, 
                        { "Alan", "Poe", "Main Street 3", 12, true } };

                //Send data to the model
                myModel.setData(data);
            }
        });

        //Add components to the window
        add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);        //Add first button
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);   //Add scroll pane
        add(button2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);       //Add first button


        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    /**
     * Model
     * 
     * @author Moreno
     *
     * @see AbstractTableModel
     */
    class TableModelCustom extends AbstractTableModel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        // Columns
        private String[] columnNames = { "Name", "Surname", "Direction", "Age", "Sport" };
        // Data
        private Object[][] data = { { "Peter", "Serry", "Rue....", 5, false },
                { "Paul", "Hey", "XXX", 13, true },
                { "Patriks", "--", "XXX", 26, false },
                { "Alice", "Hall", "XXX", 24, true },
                { "Mary", "Houstong", "XXX", 12, false } };

        /**
         * This method receives the new data vector, and update the table
         * 
         * @param data
         *            with new values
         */
        public void setData(Object[][] data) {
            this.data = data;       //Save data..
            fireTableDataChanged(); //Update table
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();  //Create the window
    }
}
```

I attach you some screen shots too.

[Default content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPhx9.png)

[Clicking one button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLyJC.png)

[Clicking other button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEe8y.png)